# Can I run other programs with Python?

Tags: python, external, audacity

Let me be more specific.

I want to create a series of audiofiles, each containing a range of frequencies.
That is done most easily with Audacity, but it would take forever to do it manually
since there are a lot of frequencies to deal with.
So the question is:

Can I make a script that will open Audacity, press all the required buttons within the program and fill in the necessary values, and then save the files?

If that's also confusing, can I use Python to make a script that will move the cursor to a specific location, order it "to click" something?

Comment: Seeing Python is a Turing complete language, it is possible. In reality, also depending on your OS, python is probably not the best language to do this task.

Comment: Not only is this possible, it is what Python was originally designed for.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out Audacity's [scripting wiki](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/scripting.html). Once you get that up and running you can use the `subprocess` module to call external commands via python.